# Is "Fastest possible route" an allowed class of questions?

Tags: discussion

There are a number of interesting Q&As on the site about whether it's possible to get from X to Y within a tight window of time.  However, this question was closed for violating the WANTA rule:

[Ambitious return trip from Germany to Australia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/131136/ambitious-return-trip-from-germany-to-australia)

Isn't that meant more for the "how many days should I spend in Paris" crowd?

Answer (score 5):

I voted to close as a WANTA question, because rather than trying to suss out a difficult-to-find reference, it is basically asking the community for help building an itinerary based on arbitrary personal requirements: how do I get from point A to point B between datetime C and D for under £E in cabin F, etc. etc. Under the old closevote system, this would have been a classic example of a question that is "too localized":

> This question is unlikely to ever help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.

Travel isn't a super-busy stack compared to, say, SU or Math, so I don't think we need to be as rigid about borderline questions, but I thought this question sounded too much like an *Amazing Race* segment.

Comment: Hey, I like *Amazing Race*!  So would the question better if it was explicitly rewritten to "is it possible to travel from Freiburg to Adelaide in under 36 hours"?

Comment: @jpatokal I also like *The Amazing Race* (as do many other TSE regulars, I'm sure), but a fun question is not necessarily a good question. I would not have CVd if the OP had articulated a good reason for the constrained travel window, that other people might similarly face, even if with different dates and different O/D points. But as written it doesn't reach my standard, and I was the last closevote, so it apparently didn't reach others' standards either.